# Torch 7/Lua cannot require a .so file, but package.loadlib() can

Tags: lua, require, torch

I get a problem when playing Torch 7 code. I have a shared library libhashnn.so file, and I want to load the functions in Torch 7 script, so I use this expression: `require 'libhashnn'`, but the trepl gives an error.

However, if I use `package.loadlib`function, it does work. Here are the results, but I don't know why I can't use `require`, how can I use `require` to load lib successfully?

```
require'libhashnn'
/home/dazhen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:383: bad argument #1 to '?' (table expected, got string)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/dazhen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:383: in function 'require'
    [string "_RESULT={require'libhashnn'}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/dazhen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:650: in function 'repl'
    ...zhen/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
```

and

```
f=package.loadlib('libhashnn.so' ,'luaopen_libhashnn')
[0.0195s]   
th> f
function: 0x41630f38
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function that `package.loadlib` gives you. I bet you will then get the same error that you get when you use `require`.

To understand why: `require` does the equivalent of `package.loadlib` and then calls that function so that the module that you are loading can initialize itself. With just `package.loadlib`, this initialization is not done and so the error that occurs during initialization does not show up.

I don't know what hashnn is and so I cannot tell you why it is broken, but looking at `/home/dazhen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua` line 383 might be a good start to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I found sometimes in the script this `require 'libhashnn'` can work with no error, but sometimes it cannot...Still confused.